# Purpose and behaviour of init() in Vertx class

Tags: vert.x, vertx-verticle

I have the following verticle for testing purposes:

```
public class UserVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserVerticle.class);

  @Override
  public void start(Future<Void> sf) {
    log.info("start()");
    JsonObject cnf = config();
    log.info("start.config={}", cnf.toString());
    sf.complete();
  }

  @Override
  public void stop(Future<Void> sf) {
    log.info("stop()");
    sf.complete();
  }

  private void onMessage(Message<JsonObject> message) { ... }
    log.info("onMessage(message={})", message);
  }

}
```

Is is deployed from the main verticle with

```
  vertx.deployVerticle("org.buguigny.cluster.UserVerticle",
                 new DeploymentOptions()
                 .setInstances(1)
                 .setConfig(new JsonObject()
                        .put(some_key, some_data)
                        ),
                 ar -> {
                   if(ar.succeeded()) {
                     log.info("UserVerticle(uname={}, addr={}) deployed", uname, addr);
                     // continue when OK
                   }
                   else {
                     log.error("Could not deploy UserVerticle(uname={}). Cause: {}", uname, ar.cause());
                     // continue when KO
                   }
                 });
```

This code works fine.

I had a look at the `Verticle` documentation and *discovered* an `init()` callback method I didn't see before. As the documentation doesn't say much about what it really does, I defined it to see where in the life cycle of a verticle it gets called.

```
  @Override
  public void init(Vertx vertx, Context context) {
    log.info("init()");
    JsonObject cnf = context.config();
    log.info("init.config={}", cnf.toString());
  }
```

However, when `init()` is defined I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException` on the line where I call `JsonObject cnf = config();` in `start()`:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle.config(AbstractVerticle.java:85)
    at org.buguigny.cluster.UserVerticle.start(UserVerticle.java:30)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.lambda$doDeploy$8(DeploymentManager.java:494)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.executeTask(ContextImpl.java:320)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.EventLoopContext.lambda$executeAsync$0(EventLoopContext.java:38)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:462)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:897)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

My questions are:

**Q1** : any clue why `NullPointerException` is thrown?

**Q2** : what is the purpose of `init()`? Is it internal to Vertx or can it be be implemented by client code to, for example, define some fields in the verticle objects passed in deployment config ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `init` method is for internal usage and documented as such in the Javadoc. Here's the source code:

```
  /**
   * Initialise the verticle.<p>
   * This is called by Vert.x when the verticle instance is deployed. Don't call it yourself.
   * @param vertx  the deploying Vert.x instance
   * @param context  the context of the verticle
   */
  @Override
  public void init(Vertx vertx, Context context) {
    this.vertx = vertx;
    this.context = context;
  }
```

If `init` is documented in any user documentation it's a mistake, please report it.

Comment: Ok, then it's clear. `init()` doc is in the javadocs with almost the same text as `start()`: *Start the verticle instance. Vert.x calls this method when deploying the instance. You do not call it yourself.* Hence my confusion. Thanks.